# Some apparently simple algebraic manipulation I just cant figure out ....

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found the following equation in a paper im reading with the caption, that it is a simple algebraic manipulation without any furhter explanation. I just cant figure out how they did it.

In the following it is $c\in(0,1)$ and $a,b \geq 0$ with $a\neq b$
\begin{align*}
   &
   \frac{2(1-c)}{a-b}
   \left(
      \frac{a}{
         a+1-c+\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}
      }
      -
      \frac{b}{
         b+1-c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}
      }
   \right)
   \\
   =\,\,\,\,\,&
   \frac{1}{a-b}
   \left(
      \frac{4(1-c)}{
         \sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2} + 1 + c
      }
      -
      \frac{4(1-c)}{
         \sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2} + 1+c
      }
   \right)
   \\
   =\,\,\,\,\,&
   \frac{8(1-c)}{
       \sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}
   }
   \,\,
   \cdot
   \,\,
   \frac{1}{
      (\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2} + 1+ c)
      (\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2} + 1+ c)
   }
\end{align*}

Comment: One technique to deduce the algebraic steps is to start from the back, that is, from the result proceeding backwards. In case you doubt the paper's procedure or results, give numerical values to the variables and check "balancing" the equivalencies.

Comment: I allready plotted the graphs, all is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let me fill in some of the gaps.

$$\frac{2(1-c)}{a-b}\Bigg(\frac{a}{a+1-c+\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}} - \frac{b}{b+1-c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}}\Bigg)$$

$$ = \frac{2(1-c)}{a-b}\Bigg(\Bigg(1-\frac{1-c+\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}}{a+1-c+\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}}\Bigg) - \Bigg(1-\frac{1-c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}}{b+1-c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}}\Bigg)\Bigg)$$

$$ = \frac{2(1-c)}{a-b}\Bigg(\frac{1-c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}}{b+1-c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}} - \frac{1-c+\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}}{a+1-c+\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}}\Bigg)$$

Consider:

$$ \frac{1-c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}}{b+1-c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}}$$

$$ =\frac{1-c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}}{b+1-c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}}\cdot\Bigg(\frac{1+c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}}{1+c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}}\Bigg)$$

I won't write out the expansion (of the numerator), but this simplifies to:

$$\frac{2\big(b+1-c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}\big)}{\big(b+1-c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}\big)\big(1+c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}\big)}$$

$$ = \frac{2}{\big(1+c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}\big)}.$$

By symmetry, we can do the same to the fraction involving $a$. Substituting into where we left off, we get:

$$ = \frac{2(1-c)}{a-b}\Bigg(\frac{2}{\big(1+c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}\big)} - \frac{2}{\big(1+c+\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}\big)}\Bigg)$$

$$ = \frac{1}{a-b}\Bigg(\frac{4(1-c)}{\big(1+c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}\big)} - \frac{4(1-c)}{\big(1+c+\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}\big)}\Bigg)$$

In the home stretch now:

$$ = \frac{4(1-c)}{a-b}\Bigg(\frac{1}{\big(1+c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}\big)} - \frac{1}{\big(1+c+\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}\big)}\Bigg)$$

$$ = \frac{4(1-c)}{a-b}\Bigg(\frac{\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2} - \sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}}{\big(1+c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}\big)\big(1+c+\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}\big)}\Bigg)$$

$$ = \frac{4(1-c)}{a-b}\Bigg(\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2} - \sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}\Bigg)\Bigg(\frac{1}{\big(1+c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}\big)\big(1+c+\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}\big)}\Bigg)$$

Consider

$$\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2} - \sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}$$

By the difference of two squares again,

$$ = \frac{\big(2a+(1-c)^2\big)-\big(2b+(1-c)^2\big)}{\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}\big) + \sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}}$$

$$ = \frac{2(a-b)}{\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2} + \sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}}$$

Substituting in to where we left off again, we get:

$$ = \frac{4(1-c)}{a-b}\Bigg(\frac{2(a-b)}{\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2} + \sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}}\Bigg)\Bigg(\frac{1}{\big(1+c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}\big)\big(1+c+\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}\big)}\Bigg)$$

$$ = \Bigg(\frac{8(1-c)}{\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2} + \sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}}\Bigg)\Bigg(\frac{1}{\big(1+c+\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}\big)\big(1+c+\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}\big)}\Bigg)$$

as required.

---

Not completely trivial (and even worse to write out in LaTeX), so don't worry that you didn't spot it. When doing algebra, always just hold your nerve. Often, it doesn't look anything like the result -- until it suddenly does. Corrections are welcome.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Sadly, I allready managed to solve it. If one substitutes $u$ for $\sqrt{2a+(1-c)^2}$ and $v$ for $\sqrt{2b+(1-c)^2}$, i.e. for example $a=(u^2-(1-c)^2)/2$, one can see the polinomials better. Then simple factoring. AND it is easier to write in Latex, trust me. I really appreciate the efford though :)